# Create a Drupal 7 node by email and populate multiple fields

Tags: feeds, emails

I'm trying to import an email from Salesforce to drive node creation in Drupal 7. I've got mailhandler/feeds set up to do most of the heavy lifting, but the one thing I can seem to figure out is how to populate 4 separate fields in the node from a single email.

I know I can map the subject line as one field and the body as another, but isn't there a simple way to parse the body content into three distinct fields?

Comment: is there any way to identify these parts of the mail?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) that allows you to modify data before it gets saved. Then create a custom plugin if needed.

Comment: DnBase, thanks for the reply! I'll have to take a look at Feeds Tamper.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you aren't already aware, there is a Salesforce module available.  See drupal.org/project/salesforce.

The project page says it supports pulling Salesforce data into Drupal, so it may fit the bill.

Comment: MEsch, thank you; I didn't know this module even existed. SFDC doesn't like data flowing out programmatically, so I didn't think a module like this was an option.